# Give an example of unbounded and entire function on $\mathbb{C}$ such that its restriction on $\mathbb{R}$ is real valued bounded function. Justify

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, entire-functions

Give an example of unbounded and entire function on $\mathbb{C}$ such that its restriction on $\mathbb{R}$ is real valued bounded function. Justify

I don't have any idia of such example. Please help with justification.

Comment: Let me just add that there actually exist entire functions that are bounded on every line in $\mathbb{C}$, but are obviusly unbounded (actually, even a stronger statement is true: there exists entire functions that go to zero on every line, without being globally bounded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Trigonometric functions.